# Problem with MySQL tinyint and Entity Framework code first

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, ef-code-first

When I want to connect to MySQL by Entity framework (code first) I get this error:

```
(22,12) : error 2019: Member Mapping specified is not valid. The type 'Edm.Byte[Nullable=False,DefaultValue=]' of member 'Permission' in type 'News.Models.Author' is not compatible with 'MySql.tinyint[Nullable=False,DefaultValue=]' of member 'Permission' in type 'CodeFirstDatabaseSchema.Author'.
```

The name of colum in db is Permission with tinyint datatype. and the below is my class.

```
   public class Author
    {
     ...
     public byte Permission { get; set; }
     ...
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fixed in Connector/Net 6.4.5 which is not out yet.

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=62135

Answer (score 0):

According to this [table](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/DataTypeMapping.html), you should be using `sbyte` as Author.Permission type.

Comment: Its not work. when I use sbyte I will faced this error: There is no store type corresponding to the EDM type 'Edm.SByte' of primitive type 'SByte'.

Comment: Are you sure you're using most recent [connector](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net)?

Comment: Yes, I use MySQL Connector/Net 6.3.6

Answer (score 0):

Are you explicitly mapping it using the Fluent API or something? Because I just ran code and when EF Code First generated my database tables, it used tinyint automatically.

Edit: I did it again with the following Fluent API mapping and it still worked perfectly.

```
mb.Entity<TestObject>()
  .Property(u => u.test)
  .HasColumnType("tinyint");

public class TestObject
{
  public long ID { get; set; }
  public byte test { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What version of EF are you using? What database are you using?

Comment: MySQL Connector/Net 6.4.3 and  MySQL Server 5.5.14